# “Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords.”

Tags: mysql, database

When trying to connect to my remote mysql server through the .NET connector I received the above error.

I've searched around and found the fix to query the following:

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0;
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('my_password');
```

The query executes successfully however I still get the error when trying to connect. What could be the issue here?

What could be the issue here??

I'm truly stuck at this issue. I've tried what I could but nothing has worked so far and I really don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using 4.1 style passwords?

Comment: @RobertHarvey
I'm not very familiar with it but I think I've turned old passwords off and then updated my current password - shouldn't that make it a 4.1 password?